# .csv file has row limit? (VBA)

Tags: vba, csv, append

I wrote a code that will transfer date from an .xls file to a csv file. But the code cuts out once the .csv file hits it's 1Million row limit mark, just like a regular excel file. You will see where I put mainwb.activate where I paste information into the csv. I think this may have something to do with how Im pasting it, but I'm not sure. Thanks.

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesInFolder_Click()

Dim mainwb As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim main_i As Long
Dim wb_i As Long
Dim transfer_array(1, 14) As Variant

Set mainwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\n808037\Desktop\csv\test.csv", ReadOnly:=False)

mainwb.Activate

Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\...")

main_i = 1

For Each fileObj In FolderObj.Files     'loop through the files

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileObj.Path)

'workbook row counter
    wb_i = 2
Do While wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb_i, 1) <> ""

    For i = 1 To 13
        transfer_array(1, i) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb_i, i).Value
    Next i

mainwb.Activate 'THIS WILL BE WHERE I OPEN AND PASTE TO THE CSV FILE

    For i = 1 To 13
    mainwb.Worksheets("test").Cells(main_i, i).Value = transfer_array(1, i) & ""
    Next i

    mainwb.Worksheets("test").Cells(main_i, 14).Value = Now & ""

    wb_i = wb_i + 1
    main_i = main_i + 1
Loop

wb.Activate
wb.Save
wb.Close

Next fileObj

mainwb.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it have a row limit?  You're opening it as an Excel file.

Comment: What should I be writing then?

Answer (score 0):

This is just one way to do this:
Add a reference to your project to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library.  Create a file object for your csv file.  You can then use the OpenAsTextStream method to read, write, or append to the csv file.  As long as you are dealing with the file as an Excel workbookyou are going to have the same limitations as Excel.  Since you are now dealing with it as text it will also be up to you to add the comma delimiter (or stuff like quotes around string values, etc...)

Comment: The *second* way to do this is to use Excel to create the .csv files individually, then use any number of methods to append them to each other without using Excel.